# How to remove the /category/ from the URL in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

So, I have a website for news and I have the following:

www.mywebsite.com/category/football

www.mywebsite.com/category/basketball

www.mywebsite.com/category/tennis

Etc... how can I remove /category/ from these, so it only works with /football dir.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is use a plugin and not .htaccess rewrite rules or changes to the permalink settings in WP admin. The plugins below will remove the category base for category archive pages as well as single posts. The category or tag base will revert to normal when the plugins are deactivated without post 404's.

See http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/ and, if needed, http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-tag-base/

Answer (score -2):

http:/yourblog.com/category/quotes/

If you want to remove /category/ from the url, follow these two steps:

1. Go to Settings >> Permalinks and select Custom and enter: /%category%/%postname%/
2. Next set your Category Base to /.

Save it and you’ll see your URL changed to this format:
http:/yourblog.com/quotes/

Taken from http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/daily-tip-quick-trick-to-remove-category-from-wordpress-url/

Comment: This is buggy, according to the site comments, and doesn't remove the category base from single posts.